# Python IDE with jupyter notebook integrated?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ide

I usually start building up code in a jupyter notebook, and then make that into a function/ class that I drop in multiple files. To access/ edit those files I used Xcode. Whereas this works more or less ok, it does require to reload the classes/ functions on the jupyter notebook every time I make a change and having to use two different softwares to code seems unsatisfying. What is the optimal way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/pycharm/)? It comes with an extension that runs Jupyter inside the IDE.